# EF core 2.2 - projection as a parameter to a generic respository error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, projection, ef-core-2.2

I have in my base repository a method like so:

```
public async Task<TEntity> GetByCondition(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, Func<DbSet<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>> baseQuery = null, Expression<Func<TEntity, TEntity>> projection = null)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> q = _context.Set<TEntity>();

            if (baseQuery != null)
            {
                q = baseQuery(_context.Set<TEntity>());
            }
        if (projection != null)
        {
            q = q.Select(projection);
        }

        return await q.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
```

I try to call this method like so:

```
Expression<Func<Businesses, bool>> predicate = x => x.Id == id && x.Status == (int)EnumGringo.LU_Status.active;

            IQueryable<Businesses> baseQuery(DbSet<Businesses> x) => x.Include(c => c.BusinessDetails)
                                                                      .Include(c => c.BusinessFacilities).ThenInclude(c => c.Facility)
                                                                      .Include(c => c.BusinessImages);


            Expression<Func<Businesses, Businesses>> projection = x => new Businesses
            {
                BusinessDetails = x.BusinessDetails.Where(bd => bd.Status == (int)EnumGringo.LU_Status.active && bd.LanguageTypeId == (int)EnumGringo.Lu_LanguageTypes.he).ToList(),
                Name = "Name projection"
            };

            Businesses business = await _repository.GetByCondition(predicate, baseQuery, projection);
```

At this stage I get an error like:

> Expression of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[DAL.Models.BusinessDetails]'
>   cannot be used for parameter of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DAL.Models.BusinessDetails]'
>   of method
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DAL.Models.BusinessDetails]
>   ToList[BusinessDetails](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DAL.Models.BusinessDetails])'

So I have 2 questions:
1) How do I make it to work?
2) Is there any difference If I send the projection argument or just filter my entity later like so?

```
Businesses business = await _repository.GetByCondition(predicate, baseQuery);
            business.BusinessDetails = business.BusinessDetails.Where(bd => bd.Status == (int)EnumGringo.LU_Status.active && bd.LanguageTypeId == (int)EnumGringo.Lu_LanguageTypes.he).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
    if (projection != null)
    {
        q = q.Select(projection);
    }

    return await q.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Try to first filter the `IQueryable` and then get the projection like this:

```
    q = q.Where(predicate);

    if (projection != null)
    {
        q = q.Select(projection);
    }

    return await q.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: Can you explain in a few words what is the difference?

Comment: Even though it is a `IQuerable` all time, the order with which you apply extension methods still matters for `IQuerable` provider. It's easier to imagine with for example `.Take(5).Where(x => x.Prop == "value")` vs `.Where(x => x.Prop == "value").Take(5)` - in the first `IQuerable` it will first take first 5 results and then filter them, and in the second example the provider will filter first, and then take 5 from the filtered ones